# not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: sql, database, oracle, expression

I am creating the following sql query:

```
SELECT B.AFLEVERING_ID,A.NAAM, COUNT(B.AFLEVERING_ID) AS aantal_keer_bekeken
FROM BEKEKENVIA B, AFLEVERING A
WHERE A.AFLEVERING_ID = B.AFLEVERING_ID
GROUP BY B.AFLEVERING_ID
ORDER BY B.AFLEVERING_ID ASC;
```

Why gives it the error:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 42 Column: 24
```

Why is this and how can I solve this? It is Oracle SQL.

Comment: I think you need to group by all columns that are not part of the aggregate, try to include A.NAAM in your group by

Comment: If it's not aggregated, group by it; your missing `A.NAAM` in your `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every column listed in the `SELECT` that is not an aggregate function result (`SUM()`, `AVG()`, `COUNT()`, `MIN()`, `MAX()` and so forth) has to be listed in the `GROUP BY`. You've selected `B.AFLEVERING_ID` and `A.NAAM`, so your group by has to include both of them.

```
SELECT B.AFLEVERING_ID,A.NAAM, COUNT(B.AFLEVERING_ID) AS aantal_keer_bekeken
FROM BEKEKENVIA B, AFLEVERING A
WHERE A.AFLEVERING_ID = B.AFLEVERING_ID
GROUP BY B.AFLEVERING_ID, A.NAAM
ORDER BY B.AFLEVERING_ID ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Why is this and how can I solve this? It is Oracle SQL.**

**Why is this:**
Think about what the database has to do
You've asked for a count of all B.Aflevering_Id's Grouped by B.Aflevering_Id
But you've also included A.Naam in your select statement.  Since each A.Naam could be different for each row, the database doesn't know WHICH A.Naam to return as you didn't group by it

So say data looked like:

```
1 blue
1 red
1 white
2 green
2 purple
2 pink
2 green
```

If you just returned the count of each aflvering_ID you would get

```
3 1's and
4 2's
```

But you also said you wanted the A.Naam

so the database says I don't know which of the blue, red, white from 1 you want.
You have 4 options, I can only use 1; so which?  It can't decide due to lack of rules; so the engine returns an error.

If you added A.Naam to the group by you may not get the desired results, if you said max or min you may get what you want but the database can't figure out what to do in this case as not enough instruction has been provided to the database engine to provide consistent results.  The engine knows this; which is why you get the error.

**How can I solve it:**
The answer to this depends on the desired results

1. You could simply remove A.NAAM from the select
2. use wm_Concat or List_Agg to get a separated list of all values
3. add it to the group by to return each row individually (in my example the green 2 would return a count of 2 all others would be 1
4. use min or max to return just the highest or lowest A.Naam

Other options exist as well but one of those four will likely address what you're trying to do.  The question is what expected result are you after?